# Create multiple canvas with different svg images sources Angualr / TS to Excel Export (DevExpress)

Tags: angular, dom, canvas, devextreme, exceljs

I'm trying to export multiple Charts and a Grid to excel in different sheets using DevExtreme. It has a native exporter in DevExtreme, but for Charts only works for PDF export. I found some solutions using the Canvas from HTML, but DevExtreme dont create Canvas, the only info i have is the SVG.

Actually i found a solution but only worked when exporting 1 Chart.

And this is how it worked.

```
 const chartsInstances = this.dxCharts.toArray();

    const workbook = new Workbook();
    const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Main sheet');

    const scale = window.devicePixelRatio;

    const svgChart = chartsInstances[0].instance.svg();

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var svgImage = new Image();
    var h = 400;
    var w = 580;
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas['style']['width'] = `${Math.round(w / scale)}px`;
    canvas['style']['height'] = `${Math.round(h / scale)}px`;
    canvas['style']['margin'] = '0';
    canvas['style']['padding'] = '0';
    var svgtext = svgChart;

    svgImage.onload = function () {
      ctx.drawImage(
        svgImage,
        0,
        0,
        Math.round(w / scale),
        Math.round(h / scale)
      );
    };

    svgImage.src =
      'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(svgtext);

    let counter = 1;
    exportDataGrid({
      component: e.component,
      worksheet,
      topLeftCell: { row: 2, column: 2 },
      autoFilterEnabled: true,
      customizeCell: ({ gridCell, excelCell }) => {
        excelCell.value = undefined;
        if (counter == 1) {
          counter++;
          chartsInstances.forEach((chart) => {
            const image = workbook.addImage({
              base64: canvas.toDataURL(),
              extension: 'png',
            });

            worksheet.getRow(excelCell.row).height = 90;
            worksheet.addImage(image, 'A3:P23');
          });
        }
      },
    }).then(() => {
      workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then((buffer) => {
        FileSaver.saveAs(
          new Blob([buffer], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }),
          'DataGrid.xlsx'
        );
      });
    });
```

But in this case above, it was just a test. Then i created this service.

```
 exportGridAndCharts(
    filename: string,
    dataGridComponent: DxDataGridComponent,
    gridSheetName: string,
    dataChartComponent: DxChartComponent[],
    chartSheetName: string,
    title: string,
    subtitle?: string
  ): void {
    const workbook = new Workbook();
    const gridWorksheet = workbook.addWorksheet(gridSheetName, {
      views: [{ showGridLines: false }],
    });
    const chartWorksheet = workbook.addWorksheet(chartSheetName, {
      views: [{ showGridLines: false }],
    });
    exportDataGrid({
      component: dataGridComponent.instance,
      worksheet: gridWorksheet,
      autoFilterEnabled: true,
      topLeftCell: { row: 4, column: 1 },
      customizeCell: function (options) {
        const { gridCell, excelCell } = options;

        if (gridCell.rowType === 'data' || gridCell.rowType === 'header') {
          excelCell.alignment = { horizontal: 'left' };
          excelCell.border = {
            top: { style: 'thin' },
            left: { style: 'thin' },
            bottom: { style: 'thin' },
            right: { style: 'thin' },
          };
        }
        if (gridCell.rowType === 'header') {
          excelCell.fill = lightGrayBackground;
        }
        if (gridCell.rowType === 'totalFooter') {
          excelCell.fill = {
            type: 'pattern',
            pattern: 'solid',
            fgColor: { argb: 'DADADA' },
          };
        }
      },
    })
      .then((cellRange) => {
        if (dataChartComponent.length > 0) {
          const quantLinhas = 20;
          const colunaMaxima = 'P';

          // Inserção dos gráficos vindos das imagens na base 64.
          let c = 3;
          let l = quantLinhas + 3;

          dataChartComponent.forEach(async (chart) => {
            c = c + 2;
            l = l + 2;

            const scale = window.devicePixelRatio;

            const svgChart = chart.instance.svg();

            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            var svgImage = new Image();
            var h = 400;
            var w = 580;
            canvas.width = w;
            canvas.height = h;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas['style']['width'] = `${Math.round(w / scale)}px`;
            canvas['style']['height'] = `${Math.round(h / scale)}px`;
            canvas['style']['margin'] = '0';
            canvas['style']['padding'] = '0';
            var svgtext = svgChart;

            svgImage.onload = function () {
              ctx.drawImage(
                svgImage,
                0,
                0,
                Math.round(w / scale),
                Math.round(h / scale)
              );
            };

            svgImage.src =
              'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(svgtext);

            const imageExcel = workbook.addImage({
              base64: canvas.toDataURL(),
              extension: 'png',
            });

            chartWorksheet.addImage(imageExcel, `A${c}:${colunaMaxima}${l}`);
          });
        }
        // logo cell
        const logoCell = gridWorksheet.getCell('A2');
        const logoColumn = gridWorksheet.getColumn('A');
        const logoRow = gridWorksheet.getRow(2);
        logoColumn.width = 22.66;
        logoRow.height = 41.625;
        const image = workbook.addImage({
          base64: gerdauLogoBase64,
          extension: 'png',
        });
        gridWorksheet.addImage(image, {
          // @ts-expect-error Issue with ExcelJs types
          tl: { col: 0, row: 1 },
          // @ts-expect-error Issue with ExcelJs types
          br: { col: 1, row: 2 },
        });

        // header
        const headerRow = gridWorksheet.getRow(2);
        headerRow.getCell(2).value = title;
        headerRow.getCell(2).font = titleFont;
        headerRow.getCell(2).alignment = {
          vertical: 'middle',
          horizontal: 'center',
        };
        gridWorksheet.mergeCells(2, 2, 2, cellRange.to.column);

        // subtitle
        const subtitleRow = gridWorksheet.getRow(3);
        subtitleRow.height = 20;
        gridWorksheet.mergeCells(3, 2, 3, cellRange.to.column);

        if (subtitle) {
          subtitleRow.getCell(2).value = subtitle;
          subtitleRow.getCell(2).font = subtitleFont;
          subtitleRow.getCell(2).alignment = {
            vertical: 'middle',
            horizontal: 'center',
          };
        }
      })
      .then(() => {
        workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then((buffer) => {
          saveAs(
            new Blob([buffer], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }),
            `${filename}.xlsx`
          );
        });
      })
      .catch((r) => console.log(r));
  }
```

This export the grid in a sheet but the charts are all blank in the other sheet. Its like the src of the image isnt working when its modified.

My HTML:

```
<div class="content-page">
  <dx-tab-panel
    #tabPanel
    class="dx-card card-padding full-height-container"
    [(selectedIndex)]="tabIndex"
    [deferRendering]="false"
  >
    <dxi-item title="Planilha" icon="bulletlist">
      <div *dxTemplate>
        <dx-data-grid
          #grid
          id="grid"
          height="100%"
          [dataSource]="relatorioMensal"
          [columns]="colunas"
          [columnAutoWidth]="true"
          [columnHidingEnabled]="false"
          [allowColumnReordering]="true"
          [allowColumnResizing]="true"
          [rowAlternationEnabled]="true"
          [hoverStateEnabled]="true"
          [noDataText]="gridMessage"
          (onExporting)="exportCharts($event)"
        >
          <dxo-export [enabled]="true"></dxo-export>
          <dxo-scrolling mode="virtual"></dxo-scrolling>
          <dxo-group-panel [visible]="true"></dxo-group-panel>
          <dxo-grouping #expand [autoExpandAll]="true"></dxo-grouping>
        </dx-data-grid>
      </div>
    </dxi-item>
    <dxi-item title="Gráficos" icon="chart">
      <div *dxTemplate>
        <dx-scroll-view>
          <div id="charts" class="card-padding">
            <div *ngFor="let item of chartStructure" class="dx-card card-padding">
              <div id="canvas">
                <dx-chart #graficos id="chart" palette="#003366" [dataSource]="chart">
                  <dxi-series [valueField]="item.key" [name]="item.display"> </dxi-series>
                  <dxo-common-series-settings #seriesSettings argumentField="id" type="line"> </dxo-common-series-settings>
                  <dxo-margin [bottom]="20"></dxo-margin>
                  <dxo-argument-axis [valueMarginsEnabled]="false" discreteAxisDivisionMode="crossLabels">
                    <dxo-grid [visible]="true"></dxo-grid>
                  </dxo-argument-axis>
                  <dxo-crosshair [enabled]="true" color="#949494" [width]="3" dashStyle="dot">
                    <dxo-label [visible]="true" backgroundColor="#949494">
                      <dxo-font color="#fff" [size]="9"></dxo-font>
                    </dxo-label>
                  </dxo-crosshair>
                  <dxo-legend verticalAlignment="bottom" horizontalAlignment="center" itemTextPosition="bottom"> </dxo-legend>
                  <dxo-title [text]="item.display"></dxo-title>
                  <dxo-export [enabled]="true"></dxo-export>
                  <dxo-tooltip [enabled]="true"></dxo-tooltip>
                </dx-chart>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div *ngFor="let item of chartTempoOperacaoStructure" class="dx-card card-padding">
              <div id="line-chart">
                <dx-chart #graficos id="chart" palette="#003366" [dataSource]="chartTempoOperacao">
                  <dxi-series [valueField]="item.key" [name]="item.display"> </dxi-series>
                  <dxo-common-series-settings #seriesSettings argumentField="id" type="line"> </dxo-common-series-settings>
                  <dxo-margin [bottom]="20"></dxo-margin>
                  <dxo-argument-axis [valueMarginsEnabled]="false" discreteAxisDivisionMode="crossLabels">
                    <dxo-grid [visible]="true"></dxo-grid>
                  </dxo-argument-axis>
                  <dxo-crosshair [enabled]="true" color="#949494" [width]="3" dashStyle="dot">
                    <dxo-label [visible]="true" backgroundColor="#949494">
                      <dxo-font color="#fff" [size]="9"></dxo-font>
                    </dxo-label>
                  </dxo-crosshair>
                  <dxo-legend verticalAlignment="bottom" horizontalAlignment="center" itemTextPosition="bottom"> </dxo-legend>
                  <dxo-title [text]="item.display"></dxo-title>
                  <dxo-export [enabled]="true"></dxo-export>
                  <dxo-tooltip [enabled]="true"></dxo-tooltip>
                </dx-chart>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </dx-scroll-view>
      </div>
    </dxi-item>
  </dx-tab-panel>
</div>
```